# How to create IN OUT or OUT parameters in Java

Tags: java, language-agnostic, parameters, out-parameters

In PL/SQL (or many other languages), I can have IN OUT or OUT parameters, which are returned from a procedure. How can I achieve a similar thing in Java?

I know this trick:

```
public void method(String in, String[] inOut, String[] inOut2) {
  inOut[0] = in;
}
```

Where the `in` parameter represents an IN parameter and the `inOut` parameter can hold a return value. The convention would be that `String[] inOut` is an array of `inOut.length == 1`.

That's kind of clumsy.

**EDIT Feedback to answers**: Other tricks include:

- holder/wrapper classes, but I don't want to introduce any new types, callbacks, etc.
- return values: I'd like a **general** solution. I.e. one with several IN OUT parameters involved.
- wrapper for IN OUT parameter as a return value: That's a viable option, but still not so nice, because that wrapper would have to be generated somehow

Does anyone know a better way to achieve this generally? The reason I need a general solution is because I want to generate convenience source code from PL/SQL in a database schema.

Comment: *"return values: I'd like a general solution. I.e. one with several IN OUT parameters involved"* See my answer. Several IN/OUT params? Return an object instance with properties for each. Barring that, no, there's nothing better than the array trick.

Comment: When I first began learning Java, after many years of C/C++ development, I also looked for a way to pass by reference. But now, years after that, I can no longer recall the last time I wanted to do that. The array trick is less elegant than other approaches cited in these answers and comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My question would be: Why doesn't `method` *return* something? Rather than setting an in/out argument?

But assuming you *absolutely, positively must* have an in/out argument, which is a whole different question, then the array trick is fine. Alternately, it's not less clumsy, but the other way is to pass in an object reference:

```
public class Foo {
    private String value;

    public Foo(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
 }

 // ....
 public void method(String in, Foo inOut) {
     inOut.setValue(in);
 }
```

(Or, of course, just make `value` public.) See? I said it wasn't less clumsy.

But I'd ask again: Can't `method` return something? And if it needs to return multiple things, can't it return an object instance with properties for those things?

**Off-topic:** This is one of the areas where I really like the C# approach. One of the arguments against in/out arguments is that they're unclear at the point where you're *calling* the function. So C# makes you make it clear, by specifying the keyword both at the declaration of the function *and* when calling it. In the absense of that kind of syntactic help, I'd avoid "simulating" in/out arguments.

Comment: The method won't be able to return a single value, because I need a **general** solution. I have adapted the example to hold several IN OUT parameters. But maybe returning a generated result object (holding the IN OUT parameters) might actually be an option. +1 for that.

Comment: You're right about your off-topic comment. In general I don't need IN OUT parameters. But as I'm generating source code from actual PL/SQL code, I can't do without... :-/

Comment: In my case I need inout because the method is already returning something else.

Answer (score 4):

Java copies anything you pass as an argument. If you pass a primitive, inside method you have copy of that primitive, and no modifications will affect the actual variable outside method. If you pass object, you pass copy of reference, which actually references to the original object. This is the way how you can propagate modifications to the context of something that called the method - by modifying the state of the object that the reference is 'pointing' to. See more on this: [Does Java Pass by Value or by Reference?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know that Java doesn't pass actual pointers but "reference copies". That's why I came up with the array trick. That's a very common way to simulate pointers in Java...

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the pass-by-value semantics Java uses in a logical manner. There are too few people like you in today's world...

Comment: @Lukas: *I know that Java doesn't pass actual pointers but "reference copies"* Which is just another term for pointers. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: As far as I know in C/C++, you can assign a new value to a pointer that will be able to leave the scope of the method. In Java, this is not possible, as Arturs correctly explained. The "pointer" is passed by value to the method, not by reference

Comment: @Lukas: *"As far as I know in C/C++, you can assign a new value to a pointer that will be able to leave the scope of the method. In Java, this is not possible..."* Java's object references (`void foo(MyObject m)`) are exact analogs of C/C++ pointers (`void foo(MyObject *pm)`). You can assign to `m` (Java), or `mp` (C/C++), but that doesn't have any effect on anything outside `foo`. But C/C++ has pointers *to pointers*: `void foo(MyObject **ppm)`, where the effect of writing to `*ppm` can be seen in the calling method. Java's analog is the array trick the OP flagged up.

Comment: @Lukas: (continuing) But granted, I'm not immediately thinking of a Java equivalent to a pointer to a pointer *to a pointer*, `void foo(MyObject ***pppm)`. :-)

Comment: OK, that's what I meant. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh right I'm sorry. I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct way. Other techniques include:

- Passing a holder object (a bit like your 1-ary array)
- Using, e.g., an AtomicInteger
- Passing a more useful object from a business perspective that happens to be mutable
- A callback to a custom interface for receiving the result

If you think about it, the array trick is not dissimilar to passing a T* in C/C++

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I thought about those things as well, unfortunately, they won't work in my case...