# AtomicStampedReference.get() method: why parameter is array?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Some time ago I started to investigate `java.util.concurrent` package. And my question is about `AtomicStampedReference` class. The class has method

```
public V get(int[] stampHolder) {
    ...
}
```

which gets reference and stamp atomically (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there some special reasons why parameter for the method is array? Documentation says nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe (probably) it is just a hack to [simulate out parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455693/how-to-create-in-out-or-out-parameters-in-java), since in this case two values should be returned: `V` and an `int` value.

Another possibility would be to return a tuple `Tuple<V,Integer>`, but Java has no `Tuple` class, and it would maybe be less efficient to create an instance of a `Tuple` object and additionally boxing the `int`, which may be important in the context of concurrency.

Comment: It is clear that actually we get two fresh values. But why did mr. Doug Lea decide to use `int[] stampHolder` instead of using `int stampHolder` for example? This method uses only the first array element - `stampHolder[0] = p.integer`.

Comment: @DmitriyProtsenko: Well if the method was defined as `public V get(int stampHolder)`  if `stampHolder` is modified the caller won't get the updated value since it is passed by value. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: The last link is very useful. Now I don't have any questions. Thanks!