# How can I have out parameters in Java?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, out-parameters

My objective is to recursively iterate a R-way trie, and find the longest common prefix that prefixes at least two strings, and how many strings it concerns. I have written various methods to solve this, but I'm not satisfied with the technical aspects of them.

Example input:

`figure, fight, finger, english, entail`

output:

```
Longest prefix: fig

Number of Strings: 2
```

Here's how I implemented solutions:

The nodes have a `timesUsed` attribute, that increments every time that node is visited when inserting new strings to the trie.

```
    public void allPrefixes() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> timesUsed = new ArrayList<>();

        allPrefixesUtil(list, timesUsed, root, "");

        int longestPrefixIndex = getLongestIndex(list);

        System.out.println("Longest common prefix: " + list.get(longestPrefixIndex));
        System.out.println("Number of strings: " + timesUsed.get(longestPrefixIndex));
    }

    public void allPrefixesUtil(ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<Integer> timesUsed, Node x, String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.next.length; i++) {
            if (x.next[i] != null && x.next[i].timesUsed >= 2) {
                list.add(s + (char) (i + 'a'));
                timesUsed.add(x.next[i].timesUsed);
                allPrefixesUtil(list, timesUsed, x.next[i], s + (char) (i + 'a'));
            }
        }
    }
```

The code here adds every prefix that occurs more than once, so the list looks like this: `e, en, f, fi, fig`. I then find the longest among these strings and print it along with the corresponding timesUsed index. This solution uses a lot of space, so I decided to try something else.

Next, I tried this:

```
    public void allPrefixes2() {
        String longest = "";
        int timesUsed = 0;

        allPrefixesUtil2(longest, timesUsed, root, "");

        System.out.println("Longest common prefix: " + longest);
        System.out.println("Number of strings: " + timesUsed);
    }

    public void allPrefixesUtil2(String longest, int timesUsed, Node x, String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.next.length; i++) {
            Node nextNode = x.next[i];
            if (nextNode != null && nextNode.timesUsed >= 2) {
                String str = s + (char) (i + 'a');
                if (str.length() > longest.length()) {
                    longest = new String(str);
                    timesUsed = nextNode.timesUsed;
                }
                allPrefixesUtil2(longest, timesUsed, nextNode, str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Instead of adding every prefix to a list and calculating the longest, I decided to reassign the longest string whenever a longer string is encountered. This obviously did not work as Java is pass-by-value. To work around this, I changed the string and integer into single element arrays.

```
    public void allPrefixes2() {
        String[] longest = { "" };
        int[] timesUsed = { 0 };

        allPrefixesUtil2(longest, timesUsed, root, "");

        System.out.println("Longest common prefix: " + longest[0]);
        System.out.println("Number of strings: " + timesUsed[0]);
    }
```

This works, but... I'm not sure if it's clever or stupid. I could not find a better way if I want to use temporary variables.

I did however lastly make it so that the trie has a `longest` and a `timesUsed` attribute, and just directly pass those into the method. It worked but this time, adding these attributes to the trie did not sit right with me. It's odd that a generic tree would have those attributes.

So what should I do? Which is the best among all these options? What's better than all three? I'm not sure which is the best conventional and practical method here, except that the first one is not space efficient.

Comment: Yes, that's the common trick. In this specific case, you could abuse `StringBuilder` and something from `java.util.concurrent.atomic`, like `AtomicInteger`, but in the general case you need a wrapper, like the array in your invention. While hits are somewhat personalized, I have to point out that https://www.google.com/search?q=java+out+parameter gets me a number of possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806545 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403921 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824910 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455693

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Java have something like C#'s ref and out keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806545/does-java-have-something-like-cs-ref-and-out-keywords)

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is not really because Java is "pass-by-value".

The problem you are encountering is that Strings are *immutable* and when you assign a new value to the *local* parameter named `longest` it just disappears as soon as it goes out of scope.

You can get around this relatively easily by passing an array of length one instead.

```
 public void allPrefixes2() {
        String[] longest = {""};
        int timesUsed = 0;

        allPrefixesUtil2(longest, timesUsed, root, "");

        System.out.println("Longest common prefix: " + longest);
        System.out.println("Number of strings: " + timesUsed);
    }

    public void allPrefixesUtil2(String[] longest, int timesUsed, Node x, String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.next.length; i++) {
            Node nextNode = x.next[i];
            if (nextNode != null && nextNode.timesUsed >= 2) {
                String str = s + (char) (i + 'a');
                if (str.length() > longest[0].length()) {
                    longest[0] = new String(str);
                    timesUsed = nextNode.timesUsed;
                }
                allPrefixesUtil2(longest, timesUsed, nextNode, str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/12299000

Comment: Thank you, @kaya3 for pointing out my semantics error. I do believe, however, that my solution will work for the question.

Comment: Is this not what the OP is already doing in one of their solutions?

Comment: @Slaw, I changed the variable `longest` from `String` to `String[]`.

Comment: Yes, but the OP says, "_To work around this, I changed the string and integer into single element arrays_". And then in the immediately following code block they have `String[] longest = { "" };`.